# Track the last activity in laravel

Tags: laravel, session, middleware, laravel-10

In laravel auth middleware i create session variable and store the the last entering time like

```
class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    if (auth()->check()) {
        session()->put('activity_time', now()->toDateTimeString());
    }
    return parent::handle($request, $next, ...$guards);
}


protected function redirectTo(Request $request): ?string
{
   
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        
        return null;
    }

    return route('root');
}

}
```

In route

```
Route::get('/', [AuthController::class, 'index'])->middleware('guest')->name('root');
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::resource('home', HomeController::class);
    Route::resource('student', StudentController::class);
});
```

in above route we do any operations in side the auth group that time session last active is updated?

and i create another middelware for check the time diffrence like

```
class CheckLastActivityTime
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $lastActivity = session()->get('activity_time');
    // var_dump($lastActivity); die();
    if ($lastActivity) {
        $lastActivity = Carbon::parse($lastActivity);

        if (Carbon::now()->diffInMinutes($lastActivity) > 5) {
            auth()->logout();
            session()->invalidate();
            session()->regenerateToken();

            return redirect('root')->with('error', 'Your session has expired. Please log in again.');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
}
```

And this middleware register in kernel

```
protected $middleware = [
    // ...
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckLastActivityTime::class,
];
```

and i dd the $lastActivity in the middleware it's show null, how we can track the time and logout the user?

Comment: hi it is not clear what you are doing, it looks like you are trying to find when a session is expired for a user but laravel manages that out of the box. Also the auth()->check() in the authenticate middleware is always false. The CheckLastActivityTime class is not a middleware as it does not extends the middleware class.

Comment: @suxgri  in auth middleware the session last activity is updated that time  CheckLastActivityTime middleware also check last activity time and current time if difference grater tan 5 logout , i try to implement this senario

Comment: ok so i have the following questions for you: -1-does the code inside auth()->check() ever run ? i believe it should not. -2-do you have a last_activity column in the user model and if so when do you update it ? -3-why not setting the session_lifetime to 5 in the .env file that does what you are trying to do?

Comment: it is a custom middleware that does not require inheritance from any specific Laravel middleware class

Comment: @suxgri now i edit the the both middleware, in auth the time is updated, but the session is not accessed in CheckLastActivityTime

Comment: please see final answer

Answer (score 0):

move your CheckLastActivityTime::class from the:

```
protected $middleware = [
  // ...
];
```

to the:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [...];
```

then apply the middleware to the routes same as you do with the auth middleware.
Now the session will be available in the middleware, before it was not as it probably wasn't initiated yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just destroy the session it automatically destroy after the 120 min

you can see here

config/session.php

'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

you can increase and decrease the time from here.